CRACO app issue when using 'babel-plugin-import': "Can't resolve '@mui/material/ThemeProvider' in 'app/src/Component'"
I'm trying to minimize my bundle size, specifically the "@mui/material" package. I'm using the guide they have: https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/.
However, after doing all the steps in my CRACO app I get the following error when running npm start:

Failed to compile.
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/material/ThemeProvider' in '/src/Component'

I reproduced the error here https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/282r7g (You may need to go to the "Development" tab in order to see it).
Does anybody know why this might be happening?

You need to import ThemeProvider and styled from @mui/material/styles instead of @mui/material.
In your App.tsx, you need to replaces these lines:
import { ThemeProvider, StyledEngineProvider } from "@mui/material";

with these:
import { StyledEngineProvider } from "@mui/material";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

Similarly, in your Component.tsx, you need to replaces these lines:
import { Box, styled } from "@mui/material";

with these:
import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

You can take a look at this forked sandbox for the live working example of your sample code.
